# How to convert string datatype to timestamp in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Data looks like 2018/03/15 14:30:00.000 and datatype is string , I want to convert it to timestamp like 2018-03-15 14:30:00 UTC . I can convert it to timestamp on legacy version but not in standard sql version in bigquery

I used parse_timestamp function it is not working as expected getting error as Failed to parse input string "2018/03/15 14:30:00.000"

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select parse_timestamp('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%E3S', '2018/03/15 14:30:00.000')
```

with output

[image]